Why the son's wheat?
In Gabriela Mistral's poem La mujer fuerte, the third stanza is as follows:

Segar te vi en enero los trigos de tu hijo,
y sin comprender tuve en ti los ojos fijos,
agrandados al par de maravilla y llanto.

The not entirely accurate translation on LyricsTranslate.com [*] renders this stanza as follows:

I saw you harvesting your son's wheat in January,
and without understanding I had my eyes fixed on you,
enlarged, both of wonder and of weep.

If I understand the second stanza correctly, it was the woman, i.e. the mother, who sowed the seeds. Why would it be the son's wheat and not, for example, the family's? (Based on the second stanza, there is either no husband or he is just a drinker.) And how does this relate to the remainder of the poem?
[*] Striking example of an inaccuracy: "tostada frente" is translated as "toasted forehead" instead of "sunburnt forehead".

The poem is divided into four verses, each with a different theme. Using Le Guin's translation, rather than the rather clunky LyricsTranslate version, the first verse runs:

I remember your face, set deep in my days,
woman of the blue skirt and sunburnt forehead,
whom I saw in my childhood, in my land of ambrosia,
break the black furrow open in fiery April.

The poet (presumably Mistral) remembers seeing a woman when she was young. We know that the woman wears a blue "saya" - a rustic garment that Le Guin translates as a skirt - and has a tanned forehead. Clearly she is a peasant woman accustomed to laboring outdoors in the fields. In Chile, a country in the southern hemisphere, wheat is planted between April and June, and the woman is engaged in ploughing the land ready to plant the crop.
In the second verse we learn about the woman's past:

In the tavern, lifting the vile cup and drinking deep,
was the man who fixed a child to your white breast;
and under the searing brand of that memory
the seed slipped from your hand, serene.

The woman has a son, and his father frequents a tavern where he "drinks deep". This is a quite faithful translation of the Spanish ("Alzaba en la taberna, honda la copa impura"), but it is interesting to note that in early editions of the poem the line was slightly different - "Alzaba en la taberna, ebrio, la copa impura". This would translate to the even more damning "In the tavern, drunk, lifting his vile cup". Clearly the father provides no support to his family and son - this is the responsibility of just the mother. Although the woman recalls this with bitterness, she nonetheless plants the seed with serenity.
The third verse we return to observing the woman engaged on her farming duties:

In January I watched you reap your child's wheat,
and not understanding, kept watching you
with eyes widened by both tears and wonder.

It is now January, which is indeed the season for harvesting the wheat, and the poet watches the woman's labor in admiration. It is indeed slightly unusual to say "harvesting your child's wheat", rather than "harvesting your wheat", or the even more neutral "harvesting the wheat". I interpret this as a subtle sign in the text to emphasize that the woman is laboring with the main aim of supporting her son, that is, everything she does is principally for his benefit. The wheat she plants and harvests is thus essentially "his wheat", rather than hers. This particularly contrasts with the description of the other "city women" the poet has encountered, described in the fourth verse:

And even now I'd kiss the mud on your feet,
for among a hundred city women, I've never seen your face,
and still I follow your shadow in the furrows with my song.

The term which Le Guin renders as "city women" was originally "mundanas", the mundane, ordinary women one would encounter in town. We thus have Mistral setting up a contrast between a selfless country woman who works hard, with her feet in the mud, to support her son, and the elegant and sophisticated ladies who live in town. Clearly Mistral considers the unselfish, hard-working peasant woman to be a far more admirable figure, the strong woman ("mujer fuerte") of the poem's title. This is a theme which Mistral returned to many times - in an article entitled "On the Chilean woman" published in 1946 she wrote:

the female farmhand, when she harvests or cultivates, feels
embarrassed to be paid half of her salary; what is not understood is
that this worker usually works for three creatures and that these are
usually those of a drunken or lazy husband and two of his children...

 Quoted in La  tierra  tiene  la  actitud  de  una  mujer, Pedro  Pablo  Zegers, Santiago (1999). 
